# Shortlinks work only for logged in users

Tags: permalinks, shortlink

In my wordpress site, i can see this line in the code:

```php
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/?p=7736" />
```

But only if i am logged in.

If i'm not logged in I see the pretty link and canonical.

And indeed if I will try the short-link when I'm logged in I will get the right post, but if not logged i will get "page not found".

I have tried adding some permalink plugins, but none of them solves the issue.

I do want to be able to use the shortlinks for non-logged-in users also.

Any Ideas?

Comment: these are not shortlinks, they are raw URLs, what WordPress used to have before pretty URLs/permalinks/rewrite rules were added. The behaviour you're describing though is non-standard and highly unusual. Are you messing with rewrite rules and permalinks based on wether a user is or is not logged in? Either via code or via a plugin? Have you tried to isolate where the cause is located by disabling everything then turning on plugins and themes one by one until the problem returns?

Comment: Hi @TomJNowell, thanks. yes i tried disabling all plugins. i found another weird related thing which is when i use get_permalink i get the raw url and not the pretty url.

Comment: Have you confirmed via testing that the theme is not the source of the problem? What you're describing is not normal WP behaviour and requires effort to do, you would get what you want out of the box in a standard WP install.

Comment: Yes i did. and i found the problem now. i am using my custom theme side by side with "Elementor" page builder (used only for some pages). and it seems that when you activate some "header" or "footer" "Elementor" template on some of the pages it causes this weird behavior.